# WinForms Dialog: Button is cut off the screen

Tags: winforms, dialog, screen, anchor

guys!

I'm having an issue with my dialog app on only one computer where it is being tested..

(You can see on the image how I expect to see in Maximized mode and how it really looks on that computer)
[image]

I've anchored them as the following:

1) 'Path' labels -- Top,Left

2) Textboxes     -- Top, Left, Right (to it stretched to all screen width)

3) Browse buttons and Merger button -- Top, Right

Why it is cut off the screen on one computer? 
Please advise...

Comment: Are all the controls contained in a panel or are they just sitting on the form?  Also, are they the same size because of a maximum size property?

Comment: No, they just sit in the form without Panel. Would it help if I put them into Panel? (I don't have that test computer in hand to test it right away)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get what you asked whether the are same in size..

Comment: Check the AutoScale in the second machine (related to the OS font size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell what is causing the problem with your form.  Could be anything from the form size, to the anchoring style, to how the form resizes, etc etc.

The most simple solution would be to contain all of your controls in a panel.  This way the controls anchor to the panel and not the form.  I would suggest using Dock.Fill on the panel if it is to fill the whole form.  This way, when the form resizes, it will still fill the whole form and you won't have to worry about anchoring it at all (dock cancels out anchor - depending on the call order).

Seems redundant in a sense, but its a quick fix and can even allow for easier troubleshooting if you want.

Comment: The problem on our form actually seems linked to the textboxes growing in size.  Try adding anchor left for the browse buttons as well maybe if you want to avoid using a panel.